# is it possible to use several different platform devices in one platform driver (nodes from the device tree)

Tags: c, kernel, device-tree

I am writing a kernel driver for beaglebone c. My assignment: write a uart driver that receives data from the gpyo and sends it to the user I have Device Tree and I have to use two platform devices: **uart** and **gpio**
here is an excerpt from DT:

```
uarts{
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&user_uarts_s0>;

    compatible = "serial";
:
:
&gpio_pins {
        compatible = "gpio_device";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&gpio_pins>;
     };
```

I can use one platform devices (code is attached below), but how can I use two? where should I put `"gpio_device"`

```
static struct platform_driver serial8250_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name = "serial",
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
        .of_match_table = hw_match_table},
    .probe = Serial_probe,
    .remove = Serial_remove
};
static struct of_device_id hw_match_table[] =
{
        {
            .compatible = "serial",
        },
};
```

this is my first driver so please don't judge too harshly and help me!

Comment: One driver is for one device. Are they the same device or two separate ones? One driver can use another device (via the second device's driver).

Comment: @user253751
  Yes, they are different devices. one uart and several gpios

Comment: are you trying to write a serial driver that uses GPIO pins?

Comment: @user253751  we are writing a serial driver. and in it we send gpio values via uart to another device

Comment: so you doing the opposite - you are writing a GPIO driver that uses a UART?

Comment: @user253751 no.this is our assignment:
write a uart driver that receives data from the gpyo and sends it to the user

Comment: okay so you are writing a UART driver that uses GPIOs. Got it. As far as I know, you can just call the GPIO functions from your serial driver, as long as you know the GPIO

Comment: but I don't remember how to set it up so that your serial device gets a reference to the GPIO device via the device tree

Comment: [here is how to link GPIOs to their users in the device tree](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio.txt) and [here is how to use gpiod_get so your code gets the gpio descriptor from the device tree](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/driver-api/gpio/board.html#device-tree) in the serial driver

Comment: Are the GPIO lines at the other end of the serial link? Perhaps you want to implement a "serdev" device driver that implements a GPIO controller? (Similar to an I2C GPIO multiplexor but using a serial link instead of I2C.)

Comment: explanation of all pins in device tree

Comment: I already wrote the device tree, I don’t know where to write `compatible = "gpio_device"`

Comment: So is the user at the other end of the serial link?

Comment: yes the user at the other end of the serial link